# Laravel cant seem to implement search properley

Tags: laravel

blade.php file that shows all Posts from my database
Im trying to add a search bar that will filter all these posts to prioritise according to title but i cant seem to get it working at all

```xml
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 pt-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          @if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->is_admin)
            <h1 class="display-one">Bloggy</h1><h2>Admin</h2>
          @endif  
        </div>
        <!-- Check to see if the user is a guest, if they are the Add post button is hidden -->
        @if(!Auth::guest())
          <div class="col-4">
            <a href="posts/create/" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Post</a>
          </div>
        @endif
      </div>
      @if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->is_admin)
        <div class="col-4">
          <a href="/admin" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Manage Users</a>
        </div>
      @endif 
      <!-- HERE -->
      <form>
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Find user here" name="search">
      </form>
      @forelse($posts as $post)
        <ul>
          <li><a href="./posts/{{ $post->id }}">{{ ucfirst($post->title) }}</a></li>
          <li><a href="./posts/{{ $post->id }}">{{ ucfirst($post->created_at) }}</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
          <a href="{{ route('posts.showPostsByUser', $post->user) }}">{{ $post->user->name }}</a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="/tags/{{ $post->tag->id }}">{{ $post->tag->name }}</a>
        </p>
      @empty
        <p class="text-warning">No blog Posts available</p>
      @endforelse
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here is my posts controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(20);

        return view('posts/index', [
            'posts'=> $posts
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts/create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    // References
    // Jefferey Way. laracasts. Laravel 8 from scratch. laracasts.com. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'tag_id' => 'required',
            'title'=> 'required',
            'body'=> 'required',
        ]);

        $post = new Post;
        //dd(Auth::user());
        $post->user()->associate(Auth::user());
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->tag_id = $request->tag_id;

        $post->save();

        return redirect()->route('posts.index')
            ->with('success', 'Post created succesfully');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.show', [
            'post'=> $post,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.edit', [
            'post' => $post
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);

        $post->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('posts.index')
            ->with('success', 'Post updated succesfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        $post->delete();
        return redirect()->route('posts.index')
            ->with('success', 'Deleted Succesfully');
    }

    public function showPostsByUser(User $user)
    {
        $posts = Post::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
        
        return view('posts.userposts', compact('posts', 'user'));
    }

    // Search function here
    public function search()
    {
        // Check for search input
        if (request('search')) {
            $posts = Post::where('title', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')->get();
        } else {
            $posts = Post::all();
        }

        return view('posts.show')->with('posts', ＄posts);
    }
}
```

Here is my routes file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController;

use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;

use App\Http\Controllers\CommentController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Models\Tag;
use App\Model\Post;
use App\Model\Users;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [WelcomeController::class, 'index']);

Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class);

Route::get('/posts/search', [PostController::class, 'search'])->name('search');

Route::post('posts/{post}/comments', [CommentController::class, 'store']);

Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'create'])->name('register.create')->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store'])->name('register.store')->middleware('guest');

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::get('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('authenticate');

Route::resource('/admin', AdminController::class)->middleware('admin');

// Route::get('/tags/{tag}', function(Tag $tag) {
//     return view('posts/index', [
//         'posts'=>$tag->posts
//     ]);
// });

Route::get('/posts/user/{user}', [PostController::class, 'showPostsByUser'])->name('posts.showPostsByUser');
```

I cant seem to get anything working when i search in the bar on the main page my url changes to
http://localhost/posts?search=postname

And then nothing happens

Any help would be appreciated thanks, still trying to learn Laravel

EDIT:
It just seems to stay on the same page just the url changes

Comment: If you're using `?search=...`, it should be a `GET` request. `POST` requests typically don't use Query Strings like that, nor should `POST` requests return a `view()`. You probably want something like `Route::get('/posts/search', [PostController::class, 'search'])->name('search');`, then if you go to `http://localhost/posts/search?search=postname`, it should try to find all `Post` records with a `title` like `postname`.

Comment: I changed that Route but i still say on the same page just my url changes

Comment: Can you show your full routes file? You might have a conflicting route on there or something. And please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74802858/edit), don't post in the comments 

Comment: Hmm ok, nothing conflicting that I can see. I notice that your `search()` method returns `view('posts.show')`, which is the view for a single `Post`, but you're passing multiple `posts`. That should probably use `posts.index`. If you're concerned it's not working, you'll have to do some debugging. Inside of your `search()` method, you can add `dd(request()->input('search'), $posts)` after your `if ... else ...` statement, and see if that get's triggered. Sidenote, your `search()` method should also be `search(Request $request)` so you can use `$request` instead of `request()` 

Comment: Hey @TimLewis im still struggling with it
dd does nothing which leads me to believe the function doesn't even run but i cant for the life of me figure out why

Comment: Yeah, you'll know if `dd()` is running or not, so yeah, that suggests that your `search()` function isn't being hit. What's the URL you're on?

Comment: Im on http://localhost/posts when i search the url changes to
http://localhost/posts?search=Post1 and nothing else happens

Comment: That's not the right route; you have it defined as `/posts/search`, so it should be `http://localhost/posts/search?search=Post1`. So it's rendering the index method, and ignoring the `?search` Query String parameter 

Comment: You _can_ remove the `search()` method and `Route::get('/posts/search', ...)`, and just use the `index()` method for your search function, like `public function index(Request $request)`, then inside of that, `if ($request->has('search'){ $posts = Post::where(...)->paginate(20); } else { $posts = Post::orderBy(...)->paginate(20); }`, then `http://localhost/posts?seach=...` would work 

Comment: I'll post an answer for ya; 1 sec.

Comment: Sidenote, I didn't see that you were using `<form>` for the `<input name="search">`, which would "append" to the current URL. If you want the separate route, you'd simply change `<form>` to `<form action="{{ route('search') }}">`, then submitting that would navigate to `/posts/search?search=whatever`, but I think just using the `index` method (as outlined in my answer) makes more sense 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a couple options here. You *can* define a separate route for `/posts/search`, or you can hook into the existing `/posts` (index) Route:

Define a `GET` Route for this new Search URL:

`routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/posts/search', [PostController::class, 'search'])->name('search');
```

`PostsController.php`:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
  $postsQuery = Post::latest(); // `latest()` is shorthand for `orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');`
  if ($request->has('search')) {
    $postsQuery = $postQuery->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
  }

  $posts = $postQuery->paginate(20);
  return view('posts.index', ['posts' => ＄posts]);
}
```

Lastly, update the `<form>` element for this Search function:

```
<form action="{{ route('search') }}">
  <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Find user here" name="search">
</form>
```

Now, when you navigate to `http://localhost/posts/search`, you'll get 20 `Post` records, ordered by `created_at`.

If you navigate to `http://localhost/posts/search?search=example`, you'll get up to 20 `Post` records, but only those that include `example` in their `title`.

You'll notice how similar that is to the `index()` method; so you can merge them to make your code a bit more "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself):

`PostsController.php`

```
public function index(Request $request) {
  $postsQuery = Post::latest();
  if ($request->has('search')) {
    $postsQuery = $postQuery->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
  }

  $posts = $postQuery->paginate(20);
  return view('posts.index', ['posts' => ＄posts]);
}
```

You don't need `Route::get('/posts/search', ...);` anymore. Instead, if you navigate to `http://localhost/posts`, you'll get the latest 20 `Post` records. If you navigate to `http://localhost/posts?search=example`, you'll get up to 20 `Post` records, ordered by `created_at`, but only those that include `example` in the `title`.

Comment: Thanks very much for this
I implemented the changes now for any search query it brings me to a 404 not found page?

Comment: If you're going with the separate `Route::get('/posts/search', ...)`, then you need to adjust your `<form>` element around the `<input name="search">`. I'll amend my answer, but also see my comment above

Comment: Same result unfortunately i have a post titled 
Ratione quas vel officiis est
If i search Ratione or the full title i get a 404 page


http://localhost/posts/search?search=Ratione = 404 Not found

Comment: Oh of course; it's matching the `/posts/{post}` Route, which calls `Post::find($id)`, but `$id` in this case would be `"search"`, which obviously doesn't exist, and is triggering a 404. Move `Route::get('/posts/search', ...)` above `Route::resource('posts')`. This is what I meant by conflicting Routes 

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!! SO MUCH!!!!